# Selenium : switch to modal window handle gives error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have this webpage https://account.proton.me/login?language=en where I am trying to switch to modal after logging in to the page. Please note that the modal appears even if you give wrong id and password, so to reproduce you can use the same code below

```
driver.get('https://account.proton.me/login?language=en')
usernameField = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="username"]')
usernameField.send_keys("kuchbhirandom@some.thing")
passwordField = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="password"]')
passwordField.send_keys("yehbhikuchbhi")
loginbutton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[@type="submit"]')
loginbutton.click()
```

The above code gives us the modal

[image]

I ttried checking the window handles and switching to them one by one which gives me

```
driver.window_handles
['CDwindow-34B695696D2295F87F84F06321D10117', 'CDwindow-212C47AEC0CCD8240A4F9675D5B5BEF2', 'CDwindow-5A39DFE9B9C75CFA7316BF2098765D05', 'CDwindow-796B9EF6777039A036CCF7C3D452807A', 'CDwindow-1DF355426CF56902DC339955FF55C9AE', 'CDwindow-1B700B499C716086FA269E89B0ED3835']
```

```
for handle in driver.window_handles:
    driver.switch_to.window(handle)
    try:
        checkbox = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@id="checkbox"]')
        print('found')
    except:
        pass
```

but I get the same error "No such element"

Talking about solving the captch : I have an external API that does it for me, but I need to click that check box here, but stuck in switching to the modal part

Note that : to reproduce issue you can use same code above, no need to create account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you have 2 nested `iframe`s in the site,
You'll have to perform `driver.switch_to.frame()` for each of them:

```py
# After pressing "sign-in"
captcha_iframe = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[title="Captcha"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(captcha_iframe)
inner_iframe = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(inner_iframe)
# Perform captcha check
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#checkbox').click()
```

Notice that after each `switch_to`, I directly use the new driver's context, and I do not perform a search under the element I found.

Comment: How did you get to know that there were 2 nested frames here, can you point it from the page screenshot please

Comment: I right-clicked the element and pressed "inspect", it is a common practice to have nested iframes for a captcha box.
So I scrolled up in the DOM tree and saw 2 iframes there.

Comment: You could also see the page's available iframes by entering the devtools console,
Near the clear console button, theres the iframe selector feature, you can see available iframes and their names.